# php capitalizing uppercase word

Tags: php

I have a Turkish string : HAKKIMIZDA and i am trying to convert to Hakkımızda.

But it converts I character to i. So i look like : Hakkimizda.

How can i convert 'İ' to 'i' and 'I' to 'ı' char ?

```
$title = ucfirst(mb_strtolower($response["data"]["title"], 'utf-8'));
```

Also i tried to `mb_detect_encoding($response["data"]["title"])` instead of `'utf-8'`. But nothing changed.

Also i tried to `strtolower` instead of `mb_strtolower`

Comment: Stop relying on auto detection and the like. _They do not work reliably, that can be proven._ Know what encoding you have instead, then encoding does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is not legit but it works ;)

```
$title = "HAKKIMIZDAKİLER";
$modifedTitle = preg_replace(
    array("/[I]/u", "/[İ]/u"),
    array("ı","i"),
    $title
);

echo $modifedTitle."\n";
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
echo ucfirst(mb_strtolower($modifedTitle));
```